# Next.js is taking two full F5 refresh actions to show new content on a static page with `revalidate: 1`? I was expecting a single one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a blog post edit page on my Next.js project.

My post pages are using the [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) feature with a `revalidate: 1` second (currently for testing). I'll later be using something like `revalidate: 300` (5 minutes).

To update a post, this is what I do:

As an admin, I visit `/admin/post/edit/my-post-slug`, change whatever I need and save.

After saving, I'm doing a `route.push` to the post page, to see the new version in `/post/my-post-slug`.

Here is the code:

```
const savePost = async (post: BlogPost, router: NextRouter) => {
  await savePostAPI(post);
  cons POST_ROUTE = "/post/my-post-slug";
  router.push(POST_ROUTE);
};
```

It's all working as intended, with one little caveat.

This is the flow I'm getting:

```
- I'M ON ADMIN POST EDIT PAGE AND I SAVE
- I GO TO POST PAGE VIA router.push() AND I SEE THE OLD CONTENT (THIS IS EXPECTED)
- WAIT A LITLE
- I HIT REFRESH (F5) ONCE AND I RELOAD THE PAGE AND STILL SEE OLD CONTENT (NOT EXPECTED)
- WAIT A LITLE
- I HIT REFRESH (F5) AGAIN AND SEE THE NEW CONTENT
```

I'm okay with seeing the old content after `router.push()`. Next.js is supposed to always serve cached content, even a stale one, before regenerating the new version. But why don't I see the new content right after pressing `F5` for the first time? Why do I need to refresh it twice to see the new content? Doesn't `router.push` trigger a new server request and let the server know that it should regenerate the page (given the fact that is obviously stale, since `revalidate:1` will make it stale after 1 second)? Why is that happening?

Instead of using `router.push()` should I just use `window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/post/my-post-slug"` to make sure I'll send that request that will trigger the regeneration of the page?

Comment: "Doesn't router.push trigger a new server request and let the server know that it should regenerate the page?" - That would seem to be the case, even though it seems to trigger a revalidation when called for the first time. I'd suggest you use `router.reload()` rather than `window.location.href` for a more idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, I can confirm.

`router.push()` implements a client-side transition, and that does not trigger a new `getStaticProps` call. It only fetches a `JSON` object with previously generated page `props`.

I.e: This means that the page will not be revalidated no matter how my client-side transitions you perform.

Either get the fresh data using `client-side` code, or do a full page reload from time to time. At least 2 will be necessary. The first one will return `stale` data and will trigger the revalidation process. The 2nd one will get the fresh data.

Answer (score 2):

Yep two page reloads seems required per Next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) (which is annoying and not intuitive from a user perspective):

> After the 10-second window, the next request will still show the cached (stale) page
> Next.js triggers a regeneration of the page in the background.

My solution to this is to use [ISR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) together with [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) which will revalidate the data on mount. This enables the data to stay fresh even on normal routing without the need of full page reloads.